# Delegate method not executing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, delegates

I'm really having a tough time figuring out why one of my delegate methods performs perfectly, but another won't.  Here is the relevant code for the delegate that isn't working:

**SideBarController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Report.h"

@protocol ReportSelectViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
    - (void) viewSelectMonitoredArea:(Report *)report;

@end

@interface SidebarController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ReportSelectViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) Report *selectedReport;

@end
```

**SideBarController.m**

```
#import "SidebarController.h"

@interface SidebarController ()

@end

@implementation SidebarController

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [self.tableViewItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSDictionary* item = sectionArray[indexPath.row];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:item[@"title"] forKey:@"CurrentReportTitle"];

    self.selectedReport = [Report where:@{@"reportTitle": item[@"title"]}].lastObject;

    [self.delegate viewSelectMonitoredArea:self.selectedReport];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

**DetailReportViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BDBSplitViewController.h"
#import "SidebarController.h"

@interface DetailReportViewController : BDBDetailViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate, ReportSelectViewControllerDelegate >

@end
```

**DetailReportViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailReportViewController.h"

@interface DetailReportViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailReportViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SidebarController *sideBarController = [[SidebarController alloc] init];
    sideBarController.delegate = self;
}

- (void) viewSelectMonitoredArea:(Report *)report {

    NSLog(@"viewSelectMonitoredArea was called");
}
```

Another delegate written exactly the same way from another controller to the DetailReportViewController works just fine.  When I put a breakpoint right after the delegate is called, I notice that the delegate has a nil value.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
**EDIT:**
Sorry, I forgot to put in `sideBarController.delegate = self` in the DetailReportViewController.h example. It is in the original code.

Comment: where's the line where you set "`delegate`" to your `DetailReportViewController` object?

Comment: I know you got your answer but Best practice for Delegates 

if( [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewSelectMonitoredArea:)]){

[self.delegate viewSelectMonitoredArea:self.selectedReport];}

Comment: Michael - I'm a little confused by your question.  I thought that you assigned the delegate in the receivers ViewController, ala `sideBarController.delegate = self`, not the other way around?

Comment: Xeieshan - Thank you for your Best practice suggestion.  I'll be implementing it in my code.

Comment: @macboyrules : was your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

The DetailReportViewController class needs to get a reference to the "SideBarController" instance and then set itself as the delegate. In DetailReportViewController:

```
// This needs to be in the DetailReportViewController class
// Assume we have a reference to the SideBarController in the DetailReportViewController class called sideBarControllerInstance
sideBarControllerInstance.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I know that is a simple mistake, but I edited my code above, which includes the reference.  It was in the original code, I just made a mistake when I copied the code here.

Answer (score 1):

The solution spurred on by Michael Dautermann was to put

```
DetailReportViewController *detailReport = [[DetailReportViewController alloc] init];
    self.delegate = detailReport;
```

right before

```
[self.delegate createSelectMonitoredArea:self.selectedReport];
```

Thanks!